# Antenna CPW internal layer

Tags: antenna, trace, waveguide

I see on the internet showing CPW( coplanar waveguide) always placed on TOP layer with ground underneath. This is what I usually do.
Is it possible to place a CPW in an internal layer? if so what should I take in consideration? 
On top layer I have components and various signals. 
Unfortunately I can't place the GPS chip on the edge of my board and I have to route it all the way to the edge. The CPW would be 30mm long.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to place a CPW in an internal layer? if so what should
>   I take in consideration?

I'm assuming that this is intended as a transmission line feed to an antenna and not the actual antenna.

If so, it becomes a stripline like this: -

[image]

And you can use various calculators to get answers. I took the above picture from [here](https://www.pasternack.com/t-calculator-stripline.aspx). There are plenty of on-line calculators that can give answers to your problem.

If you don't have a ground plane either side but have component tracking on the top layer it can get messy.

Comment: Would be ok if the layer below is a ground plane and above only partially( only along the stripline),  so that I can still use the same layer for other signals?

Comment: I would imagine it would be OK but remember this is a transmission line and not an antenna as mentioned in your question title.

Comment: The antenna is placed externally, the strip only carry the signal to the chip. Thank you for the reply.